# Реализовать Fetch запрос для массива в котором присутствуют пустые элементы

Tags: javascript

Есть массив(tasksId) с 13 элементами, в котором есть пустые элементы и массивы с id задач.
Нужно сделать fetch запрос для каждого id, при этом никак не меняя массив. На выходе должен быть промис в которм результат будет массив, в котором для пустых элементов путсые элементаы, а для id результат в формате json. Потенциально не может срабоать потому что map просто перебирает id, но не делает запрос для него

```js
let tasksId = [ [], ['2bdbje', '26egn2', 'bvwt98'], [], [], ['zbdbje', '2hegn2', '72382'], ];//это не вссе элементы, допустим так
async function getTasksData() {
  let tasks = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < tasksId.length; i++) {
    let task = await fetch(`https://app.clickup.com/tasks/v1/task/${tasksId[i].length > 1 ? tasksId[i].map(item => item) : []}`).then(
      successResponse => {
        if (!successResponse.ok) {
          return null;
        } return successResponse.json();
      },
      failResponse => {
        return null; // что вернуть?
      }
    );
    tasks.push(task);
  }
  let results = await Promise.all(tasks);
  return results;
}
```

Comment: "Но у меня вылазит ошибка"  --- не играйте в шпиона, скажите её

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как таковой ошибки нет, все элементы возвращаются как null, в отладчике код выполняет условие tasksId[i].length > 1, но tasksId[i].map(item => item) не находит и fetch запрос подсвечивается красным, сам не до конца разобрался где код зависает, если бы разобрался, скорее всего справился бы сам